How to get only the value of two fields from a report of my Salesforce ORG via GET
on the following GET I want to take only the values of Case_number__c and Status:
https://abc.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v44.0/analytics/reports/00O2C000000eX7KUAU
How can I do It, and show explicitly be field names, because I'm only seeing something like this now:
"rows": [
                {
                    "dataCells": [
                        {
                            "label": "01290356",
                            "value": "5002C00000F5PZkQAN"
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "Global ABC",
                            "value": "Global ABC"
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "-",
                            "value": []
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "Completed",
                            "value": "Completed"
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "John",
                            "value": "0052C000003VYksQAG"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },

Thanks in advance,
Best regards,
André Rödel

If you change your API to add ?includeDetails=true as in:
`https://abc.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/data
         /v44.0/analytics/reports/00O2C000000eX7KUAU?includeDetails=true

You'll get additional information about the report dataCells as shown in this example
Specifically,
 "detailColumnInfo" : {       
      "CASENUMBER" : { "dataType" : "string", "label" : "Case Number" },       
      "XXX" : { "dataType" : "String", "label" : "XXX },       
      "YYY" : { "dataType" : "String", "label" : "YYY" },       
      "STATUS" : { "dataType" : "string", "label" : "Status" },
      "OWNER" : { "dataType" : "Id", "label" : "Owner" } }     
    }


Hi Cropredy, unfortunately, this addition didn't change the response that I'm getting since I'm already receiving the detailColumnInfo on the response, and It only shows the information about the field including Its general values, but I need to take the FieldName and Value accordingly to the Report, but thanks anyways.

@AndreRodel  - try with V60

Unfortunately, It didn't work as expected, but I've given another solution to the stakeholders, using the GET to take all the criteria on the report, but thanks for your help and all :)
